# Can't select Target Windows Phone OS Version to 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

Yesterday I've installed WP 8.1 SDK on my PC. Now, when I launch my WP project in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, version 12.021005.1, I can't choose it as Target Windows Phone OS Version - there is only Windows Phone 8.0 present on the list.
Am I missing something? In Tools submenu there's a Windows Phone 8.1 related options ("Developer Power Tools", "Developer Unlock" and "Application Deployment").
Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by lack of Visual Studio 2013 update 3. Installing it allows creating of WP 8.1 apps.